# use gulp to concat angularjs files but get [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, gulp

At first, I import every angularjs files into html and it worked fine.
However, I want to use gulp to concat these files into one file in order to reduce connection amount.
My folder structure is :

```
--- public
 |- app.js
 |- controller.js
 |- directives.js
 |- factories.js
 |- filter.js
 |---
    |--- events
       |- app.js
       |- controller.js
    ....
```

inside my /public/app.js, I declared router

```
$stateProvider
    .state('events', {
         url: "/",
         templateUrl: "/public/partial/events",
         controller: "events",
         reloadOnSearch: false
    }).....
```

I declare each pages as a folder, such as events and contain app.js and controller.js .

My events/app.js is

```
angular.module('events', ['ui.router', 'ngRoute', 'events.controller'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        }
    ]);
```

events/controller.js is

```
angular.module('events.controller', ['restangular', 'LocalStorageModule', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'Alertify', 'daterangepicker', 'ngTable', 'slick'])
    .controller('events', ['$scope','$compile', ....,
        function ($scope, $compile, ....) {
```

My gulpfile.js is simply concat all the angularjs files but got error!

```
gulp.src([
        "/public/app-v8.js",
        "/public/controller-v22.js",
        "/public/directives-v6.js",
        "/public/factories-v5.js",
        "/public/filters-v1.js",
        "/public/events/app-v0.js",
        "/public/events/controller-v23.js",
       .....
    ])
```

Comment: Is your templateUrl correct?

Comment: I think so. Because it worked well if page separately load all the angular files.

Comment: I just cannot figure out why it is broken that I just concat all the files. :(

Comment: But template url should point to a html file? In your case it is pointing to a directory

Comment: Server would handle it and render ejs file. `res.render('public/partials/' + name);` 
Any problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In your gulpfile, giv

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');

    gulp.task('pack-js',function(){
        return gulp.src(['app.js',
            'common/controllers.js',
            'common/services.js',
            ....
            ])
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('myFolder/build/js/'))
});

'bundle.js' contain all your JS files. Similarly you can do for CSS files also.

At last you can run your task like this.

gulp.task('bundle-assets',['pack-js','pack-css']);
```

Comment: I update my gulpfile.js. My angular project structure is different from your advice. I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: I have just put my 'gulp.src' as a task. so that when i run my task in terminal, it will create a 'bundle.js' where all '.js' would be there. And after 'bundle' creation , i minify it and put in one dest folder.